# Set correctly active tab when open specific URL manually in Angular

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I use Angular and Clarity. I have a navigation bar in `app.component.html`

```
<nav class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === 'home'}" (click)="onSelectTab('home')" >HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === 'contact'}" (click)="onSelectTab('contact')">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === 'help'}" (click)="onSelectTab('help')" >HELP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Snippets from `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  activeTab = 'home';

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  onSelectTab(newTab: string): void {
    this.activeTab = newTab;
    this.router.navigate([newTab]);
  }
  ...
}
```

and the routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'help', loadChildren: () => import('./help/help.module').then(m => m.HelpModule) },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

It looks like this

[image]

If I click on `contact` or `help` everything will be ok. The corresponding tab and the component will be displayed and the new url will appear in the address bar.

The problem is that if I manually open not `localhost:4200` but `localhost:4200/help` or `localhost:4200/contact` at the beginning then the corresponding component will show up. But the active tab will still be the `home`.

[image]

How can I set correctly active tab at the beginning if I manually open `localhost:4200/help` or `localhost:4200/contact` urls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling the function selectTab each time you make a click to the link you could make use of `RouterLink`.
Then with the attribute routerLinkActive you can automatically assign a class when the link desired is active.

It would like this,

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === 'home'}" 
    routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLink]="['/home']"
     >HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === 'contact'}" 
    routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLink]="['/contact']"
    >CONTACT</a>
  </li>
```

You can see a simple live example here, [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-active-route)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I need to use `routerLinkActive` directive.